# How to Parse this JSON in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, json

I'm new in iPhone programming. 
I have to parse this data in JSON in Objective-C.

{"success":1,"check":[{"ChkKey":"2","ChkDeb":"Connection 1","ChkSSID":"Netgear-1111","ChkIP":"192.168.2.103","ChkBlk":"0"}]}

I follow the example for parsing data with Json. But this JSON is so different.
It is composed by two Array.
How can i proceed?
Thanks - A.b.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What frameworks are you using? Please show relevant code. http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 3):

How about trying something like this ...

```
//JSON string
NSString *jsonString = @"{\"success\":1,\"check\":[{\"ChkKey\":\"2\",\"ChkDeb\":\"Connection 1\",\"ChkSSID\":\"Netgear-1111\",\"ChkIP\":\"192.168.2.103\",\"ChkBlk\":\"0\"}]}";

//Parse JSON string into an NSDictionary
NSError *e = [[NSError alloc] init];
NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&e];

//Output the value of success
NSLog(@"Success:%@", [jsonData objectForKey:@"success"]);

//Get data in the check array
NSDictionary *checkData = [[jsonData objectForKey:@"check"] objectAtIndex:0];

//Output the value of ChkSSID
NSLog(@"ChkSSID:%@", [checkData objectForKey:@"ChkSSID"]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much Darren.
In this way I retain what I need.

Comment: No problem at all! I am glad it helped.